# How to Get specific data drom text in Octave

Tags: arrays, file, octave

I have a problem loading data from text file in Octave.
My text file looks like this:

```
# Created by Octave 5.2.0, Wed May 05 16:07:02 2021 GMT <unknown@DESKTOP-HEVT6O6>
# name: x
# type: matrix
# rows: 1
# columns: 3600
 4.8899999999999997 4.9000000000000004 4.9000000000000004 4.9100000000000001 4.9299999999999997 4.9249999999999998 ...
```

I need to load those float numbers in one matrix and plot them in time domain.

My code so far:

```
fs = 360;
Ts = 1/fs;

d = fileread('ecg.txt');

data = regexp(d(1,136:62328),' ','split');
data = str2double(data);

ed = length(data);

t = linspace(0,Ts,ed - 1);
figure(1)
plot(t,data(1,2:ed))
```

So My question is if there is another way to do it or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Did you try `load ecg.txt` and then `plot(x)`?

Comment: No, load command ignores those comments from text?

Comment: My problem is those first five lines from my text.How can i pass them and take only the float nums

Comment: Try `d = load('ecg.txt', 'x');`, then `plot(t, d.x)`

Comment: I find it really funny that you don't try my suggested solution, you assume it's not going to work. :(

Comment: This is an interesting problem. It suggests that perhaps there's an opportunity for a usability enhancement here, to make the nature of these files clear to users. I have submitted a feature request on the Octave bug tracker ([bug #60806](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60806))

Comment: incidentally, obviously Cris' answer is 100% what you should be doing, but just to answer your literal question, you could have used `strsplit` using '\n' as the delimiter, to split `d` into a cell array of 'lines', and then simply discard the first 5 before proceeding to process the remaining lines as text.

Comment: Ok thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is in Octave’s text data format. This is the default file format when saving variables to file with [`save`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/save.html). That is, that text file was saved in Octave using `save ecg.txt x`. The Octave command `load ecg.txt` will load the file, and re-create the `x` variable just like it was when it was saved.

Thus, to plot your data, just do

```matlab
load ecg.txt
plot(x)
```